# Can my question be protected? It's attracting too many low quality/comments as "answers"

Tags: support, status-completed, protected-questions

Recently, I posted a question on Android SE [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/196459/what-is-creating-these-gibberish-files-on-my-sd-card) asking what was creating gibberish files in my SD card. It got a few hundred views, but also attracted a lot of "answers" as comments. Can it get protected? I can't do it (not enough rep), and the question needs it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though the system does this automatically after a certain amount of deleted answers (IIRC it was 5, but yours currently only has 3), I've protected it now on your request.

Comment: Hi, Izzy. If you refer to [this FAQ on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764/350567), you'll find it's **3+ deleted answers from 3+ different low-rep users**, **5+ answers from low-rep users in 24 hours**, or **2 spam-deleted answers from 2 different users**. While I'm not able to see the deleted answers, it should be that some of the answers are from one user, which doesn't count into the auto protection criteria.

Comment: @iBug 3 deleted answers from 2 different users, right. So the next one would have triggered it, according to your description. And yes, I had the number 5 in mind.